# CSS sort of DIVs from MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, css

I need help with CSS for sorting MySQL rows to 3 column layout with fixed width and AUTO height. Can anybody can post here some link with solution, I dont know which phrase I need search for.

I created easy example image:

[image]

Comment: Are you populating any html document with the values returned from a SQL query?

Comment: [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) or [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html) or [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to do this. They provide exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create 3 divs with class column :

```
<div class=column >
</div>

<div class=column >
</div>

<div class=column >
</div>
```

In css :

```
.column
{
     float: left;
     width: 30%;
}
```

Then add divs to each of your columns containing database informations you want to dump

Answer (score 0):

something like this in your php code

```
$left_column = "<div class="column">";
$center_column = "<div class="column">";
$right_column = "<div class="column">";

$q = mysql_query(/*sql query*/);
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $q)){
    $sqldata[] = $row;
}
count = 0;
foreach($sqldata as $key => $value){

    if($count % 3 == 0){
    //append $value['content'] to left column
    $left_column .= $value['content'];
    }
    else if ($count % 3 == 1){
    //append $value['content'] to center column
    $left_column .= $value['content'];
    }
    else if ($count % 3 == 2){
    //append $value['content'] to right column
    $left_column .= $value['content'];
    }
    count .= 1
}

$left_column .= "</div>";
$center_column .= "</div>";
$right_column .= "</div>";

echo $left_column;
echo $center_column;
echo $right_column;
```

css

```
.column {
float:left;
width:30%;
}
```